# Resolution of math expressions Sphinx / imgmath

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using `sphinx.ext.imgmath` to include mathematical expressions in my Python project documentation. It's working, but the resolution of the produced images is quite low. How can I make it produce images with higher resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With imgmath you can use either the png or svg format. In my experience, svg has a better resolution by default. You can enable it in your Sphinx `config.py` by defining the variable

```
imgmath_image_format = 'svg'
```

You may need to adjust the math font size. This can be done using

```
imgmath_font_size = 14  # for font size 14
```

If you really need png, then you can override the default settings for the `dvipng` application which is used by `imgmath`. The corresponding variable for `conf.py` is

```
imgmath_dvipng_args = ['-gamma', '1.5', '-D', '110', '-bg', 'Transparent']
```

which is the default. Those are key value pairs for `dvipng`. `-D` means output resolution, and its value is 110. You can increase it, but that makes the whole displayed image bigger as well. So you have to fiddle with the font size. For other dvipng options, use its command line help.

All in all, I recommend using svg. :-)